# How to pick an indexed value from a knockout array

Tags: javascript, arrays, knockout.js

I want to look up an array availableItems with an index variable 'id'. 
This is snippets from my code:

```
function Item(id, category, name, selected ) {
    var self = this;

    self.id = ko.observable(id); 
    self.Category = ko.observable(category); 
    self.Name = ko.observable(name);
    self.Selected = ko.observable(selected);   
}

function ViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    self.availableItems = ko.observableArray();

    self.init = function (){
       self.availableItems.push(new Item(1, "A", "Hello", false));
       self.availableItems.push(new Item(2, "A", "Hi", true));
       self.availableItems.push(new Item(3, "A", "Bye", false));
    }

    self.id = ko.observable(1);
}

var viewModel = new ViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
viewModel.init();
```

How come the following HTML line don´t work?

```
Indexed line: <span data-bind="text: $root.availableItems()[$root.id()].Selected()"></span>;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you have to initialize your view model before you bind it.

This will work:

```
var viewModel = new ViewModel();
viewModel.init();
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

Knockout is trying to parse and apply your bindings when you call applyBindings. But by that time your array of availableItems is still empty, thus you are getting the exception.